# CDK Reference to already cdk created RDS Database Instance to add tags

Tags: amazon-rds, aws-cdk, aws-cdk-typescript

I have a cdk created RDS cluster like below.

```
    this.rdsCluster = new DatabaseCluster(this, "MyRdsClusterId", {
      
      engine: DatabaseClusterEngine.auroraMysql({ version: AuroraMysqlEngineVersion.VER_2_11_4 }),
      credentials: Credentials.fromSecret(secret),
      clusterIdentifier: "MyRdsCluster", 
      defaultDatabaseName: "mydefaultDb",
      storageEncrypted: true,
      instanceProps: {
        instanceType: InstanceType.of(InstanceClass.BURSTABLE2, InstanceSize.SMALL),
        vpcSubnets: {
          subnetType: SubnetType.PUBLIC,
        },
        vpc: props.vpc,
      },
      removalPolicy: RemovalPolicy.RETAIN,
      storageEncryptionKey: storageKey,
    });
```

I have to add tags to rds writer instance alone. However, I am not able to add only to the instance. I am able to use *Tags.of(this.rdsCluster).add()* but this adds the tags to cluster, instances and rds subnet groups as well.

Upon checking, I see that option

1. is there to import rds instance using attributes as per [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_rds.DatabaseInstanceBase.html#static-fromwbrdatabasewbrinstancewbrattributesscope-id-attrs). But this requires me to specify security groups and ports which I don't have.
2. there is a feature request which is closed https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/7295 I think this should be re-opened

**Question:**

1. Is there any way (at least by imports) to add tags only to my rds writer instance in this case?

Comment: There is no instance resource being created here, just a cluster. A cluster can have an arbitrary number of instances, which are not managed by cloudformation.

Comment: This creates instance also.

Comment: Well, no, the instances are created by the RDS service, not by CloudFormation or your CDK code. And since the instances are not part of the template, it doesn't apply the tags to them. Cluster tags, on the other hand, are propagated to managed instances.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. So the only way to add tags to instance alone is to import it and add tag somehow ? Is it possible

Comment: No, imported resources cannot be modified. And I don't think you'd be able to import an instance that's part of a cluster. I think the solution is to tag the cluster L1 resource via `Tags.of(this.rdsCluster.node.defaultChild).add`